# Organizing the header of an HTML file

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a header of a fixed size in html where I want to organize four separate objects (although the type of objects is not super important)
- an image 
- some text 
- a button
- another button

And I want them all to be in a line, with asymmetric widths, What would be the easiest way to achieve this "organizationally". Assume the heights of each element are appropriately sized.  I am looking for a simple solution as a starting point. Here is sample code of what I have so far

```
<html>
<body>
<div id = "container"> 
<div id = "header">
<span> <img src = "test.jpg"> <h1> Testing File </h1> 
<button type = "button"> Button1 </button> 
<button type = "button"> Button2 </button></span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just float them and give them 25% widths?

Comment: Do you have an image to explain how it should look. And are you asking how to write your css? or how to organize/structure the html elements?

Comment: Look into flexible layouts (`display: flex`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `<span>` behaves as a inline container, the element messing up your layout is the `<h1>` which behaves as a block element. Simply change the display of the `<h1>` to an inline style such as inline, inline-block, or inline-flex.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   #header h1 {
    display: inline;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header" >
    <span>
     <img src="test.jpg"> <h1> Testing File </h1>
     <button type="button"> Button1 </button>
     <button type="button"> Button2 </button>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```